# Setting format React-Intl FormattedDate

Tags: reactjs, datetime, react-redux, react-intl

Where does the default format get set for FormattedDate?

Right now my dates are showing the one digit for the month: 3/9/2017

FormattedDate  value={new Date('2017-03-09')}

Can this be set in the IntlProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set formatting via the `format` prop:

```
props: DateTimeFormatOptions & {
    value: any,
    format?: string,
    children?: (formattedDate: string) => ReactElement,
}
```

Taken from the [Docs](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formatteddate)

Comment: can you provide a more specific reference to the documentation about the `format` property? I'm not being able to make it work (using `react-intl v2.7.2`)